# Why can't I rename files in the Windows 7 search results window?

Tags: windows-7

When I do a search of my mp3 folder, I cannot rename any of the files that appear in the search results window.  Yet, I CAN rename that same file if I locate it manually in the mp3 folder.  The problem is there are too many mp3 files to search for them manually each time I want to change the name of one of the files.  Is this a settings issue?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Moab, I was definitely able to rename files in a search results window when I used XP.  Did something change with 7?

Comment: I can rename in Windows 7's search results, both by right click menu and the F2 shortcut. @Paul are you searching from the start menu or from a Windows Explorer window? You can't rename from the start menu.

Comment: @Bob I'm definitely searching from a Windows Explorer window.  After I right click on the file name, I get a "ping" sound when I try to change the name.  I don't think it's a file name length issue because, as I said above, I *am* able to change the same song's file name after I manually find it in the original folder.  And again, I had no problem with renaming files in XP.

Comment: @Bob Just to be clear, I *do* see and click on the "rename" choice in the menu (as below) but once I put the cursor anywhere in the song's file name and begin to type, I get that "ping".

Comment: @Bob This is odd...one more thing I just noticed.  After clicking "rename", I can backspace to successfully delete a character - and it will "take" but then I cannot substitute a new character in its place.  In other words if the original filename was 50 characters, I can rename it with 49 successfully, but then I can't alter it back up to 50.

Comment: Have you tried renaming search results in safe mode? I'm thinking it could be some shell (Explorer) extension, and hopefully safe mode disables those. It's definitely not standard Windows behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, you can't rename then when the search results are display on the Start Menu, but you can in an actual Search window.

Results/options from Start Menu search (no Rename):

[image: Search from Start results]

Results/options in full Search Window:

[image: Results in Search Window]

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. Whenever you search for files in Windows 7's Windows Explorer, you can't rename the files in the search results if the filename is longer than a certain limit, which in my Windows 7 is 128 characters (including extension, and doesn't take into account the path where the file is in).

When you try to rename the same file in Windows Explorer in a normal folder (not in a search result), you can do it as long as the filename's length, including drive and path, is less than MAX_PATH (currently 260 characters/bytes on all modern Windows AFAIK). That is the normal limit, and I don't know why renaming in the search result has a different limit. Probably the edit box has a different coding (who knows why).

My answer is: I don't know of any way to circumvent this limit, and I've searched long about this annoying problem and found nothing at all. You'll have to do with any of the excellent third party renaming utilities that are available. I personally use BRU which is free (http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/). It is still annoying to find this problem because unless you're searching and renaming many files at once, usually search withing Explorer is much faster and comfortable. Until you hear that annoying "beep".